# NodeJs Packaging with oracledb,typeorm and packing with pkg

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm trying to package my nodejs backend project with typeorm and oracle db with pkg dependency. When I execute the .exe file an error is shown that oracle db is not installed

Comment: i already specified oracledb and typeorm in the package.json

Comment: Maybe see https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1098#issuecomment-493750589 ?

Answer (score 0):

Node-oracledb has an external dependency. Please see the install doc for details for your platform: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md